# Need increment/decrement input fields name by clicking div- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am novice in jQuery but trying to learn something very basic. I am just trying to build up auto increment/decrement input fields name inside a 'div' when CLICK add/remove button. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="add_new_agent" style="display:none;">

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="add_agent_div">
        <span id="agent-remove" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon-remove "></span>
            <label class="control-label "><small>AGENT INFORMATION <span id="count_agent">1</span></small></label>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Agent Name" name="agent_name_1" class="string required form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Agent Phone Number" name="agent_phone_1" class="string required form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Agent Email Address" name="agent_email_1" class="string required form-control">

    </div>


   <button id="add_agent" type="button" class="btn">ADD MORE AGENT</button>

</div>
```

Here i am trying to build when click `#add_agent` then new `#add_agent_div` will appear and the fields name will increase and decrease fields names when click `#agent-remove` as well.

So far, i managed to add/remove new `#add_agent_div` but i cant increase/decrease the input fields name's last digit :(

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#add_agent').click(function(e){ 
    var cloneDiv = $('.add_new_agent').find('#add_agent_div').clone(true);
        $('.add_new_agent').find('#add_agent_div').after(cloneDiv);

});
$('#agent-remove').click(function() {
    if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
        $(this).parent('#add_agent_div').remove();                    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are cloning and appending the html elements, you should not use `id`s, since ids can not appear multiple times in a page. Instead you should use classes.

For your solution, you can do this:

```
$('#add_agent').click(function(e){     
    var $htmlTemplate = $('.add_new_agent').find('.add_agent_div:first').clone(true);
    $htmlTemplate.find('.count_agent').text($('.add_new_agent').find('.add_agent_div').length+1);
    $('.add_new_agent').append($htmlTemplate);

});

$('#agent-remove').click(function() {
    if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
        $(this).parent('.add_agent_div').remove();
        $('.add_new_agent').find('.add_agent_div').each(function(e,i){
            $(this).find('.count_agent').text($(this).index()+1);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/fk82uro5/3/

Comment: wow !! really awesome and thanks for excellent suggestion to use `class` i/o `id`. Really appreciate your effort but i would love to know how to increase/decrease the input text field names  in same way  like : agent_name_1, agent_name_2 etc..

Comment: @MehediHasan in order to do that, you would need to assign class to each input fields, l ike `.agentName`, `agentNumber` and `agentPhone` and update them along with the label's text. Here, I updated the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fk82uro5/4/

Comment: great.. it works :) It's really nice to have a great solution from you. Hats off @Caner Akdeniz

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
  $('#add_agent').click(function(e){
    var currentNumber = /* parse this off the dom or keep track of the current number in your script */

    var newDiv = '<div class="row">' +
                  '<div class="col-xs-6">' +
                     '<input type="text" placeholder="Agent Name" name="agent_name_' + currentNumber + '" class="string ..."' +
                      ...; 
    $("#add_agent_div").append(newDiv);                 
  })

  $("#agent-remove").click(function() {
     /* remove last div in add agent div */ 
  })
```

Comment: It's nice to have your answer and thanks for your effort. But just i wondering when users add 3 agent & remove the agent number-2 then how can i re-arrange the existing 2 agents ? Actually i am just beginner & try to learning basic concept of this jQuery issues. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can go for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zo1r1s4f/1

HTML

```
<div class="add_new_agent">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="add_agent_div"> <span id="agent-remove" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon-remove "></span>

        <label class="control-label "><small>AGENT INFORMATION <span id="count_agent">1</span></small>
        </label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Agent Name" name="agent_name_1" class="string required form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Agent Phone Number" name="agent_phone_1" class="string required form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Agent Email Address" name="agent_email_1" class="string required form-control">
        <button class="agent_remove" type="button" class="btn">Remove</button> 
    </div>
    <button id="add_agent" type="button" class="btn">ADD MORE AGENT</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#add_agent').click(function (e) {
    var cloneDiv = $('.add_new_agent').find('#add_agent_div').clone(true);
    $('.add_new_agent').find('#add_agent_div').after(cloneDiv);

});
$('.agent_remove').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Your index is not changing accordingly. All your div indexes have this text: `AGENT INFORMATION 1`. Seems like you just copied and pasted the original question source code.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz Huh what are you saying? It just adds a remove button to every new agent and so you can remove that. It works exactly the same as yours. You don't need an index for this kind of stuff. Btw, I modified the code and why is it so bad to stay close to OP's code and search for an answer within his line of thinking. I seriously don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz Whoops, sorry for my answer. I did not see what you meant. Yeah, the number of `Agent` is not changing. Haha I was thinking of an array index. I could not figure out what OP wanted so I thought he just wanted a remove button for his agents. Well..you gave the right answer